# Python multiprocessing in function - memory usage increases with every function call

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm processing big amounts of data in parallel which works fine the first time. But when I try to wrap my program in a function and call it multiple times with different parameters(e.g. only a specific year should be processed) the memory first doubles then triples and so on until my PC runs out of memory.

I'm not sure what's going on but when I run the following minimal example of what I'm doing I get strange output of the multiprocessing logger. Basically if I call the calc() function n times the logger shows each output n times.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import logging

class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        while True:
            next_task = self.task_queue.get()
            if next_task is None:
                # Poison pill means shutdown
                print '%s: Exiting' % proc_name
                self.task_queue.task_done()
                break
            print '%s: %s' % (proc_name, next_task)
            answer = next_task()
            self.task_queue.task_done()
            self.result_queue.put(answer)
        return


class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __call__(self):
        time.sleep(0.1) # pretend to take some time to do the work
        return '%s * %s = %s' % (self.a, self.b, self.a * self.b)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s * %s' % (self.a, self.b)


def calc():

    multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)
    # Establish communication queues
    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # Start consumers
    num_consumers = 1
    print 'Creating %d consumers' % num_consumers
    consumers = [ Consumer(tasks, results)
                  for i in xrange(num_consumers) ]
    for w in consumers:
        w.start()

    # Enqueue jobs
    num_jobs = 3
    for i in xrange(num_jobs):
        tasks.put(Task(i, i))

    # Add a poison pill for each consumer
    for i in xrange(num_consumers):
        tasks.put(None)

    # Wait for all of the tasks to finish
    tasks.join()

    # Start printing results
    while num_jobs:
        result = results.get()
        print 'Result:', result
        num_jobs -= 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    calc()
    print '--------------------------------------------'
    print 'RUNNING SECOND TIME ALL CALLS ARE DUPLICATED'
    print '--------------------------------------------'
    calc()
```

The logger output is:

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730532954112
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730532921344
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730532888576
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730532855808
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730532823040
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730532790272
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730532757504
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730532724736
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730494124032
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730494091264
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730494058496
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
Creating 1 consumers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._start_thread()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] doing self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] Queue._after_fork()
[INFO/Consumer-1] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... done self._thread.start()
Consumer-1: 0 * 0
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] Queue._start_thread()
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] doing self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] ... done self._thread.start()
Consumer-1: 1 * 1
Consumer-1: 2 * 2
Consumer-1: Exiting
[INFO/Consumer-1] process shutting down
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
Result: 0 * 0 = 0
Result: 1 * 1 = 1
Result: 2 * 2 = 4
--------------------------------------------
RUNNING SECOND TIME ALL CALLS ARE DUPLICATED
--------------------------------------------
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] telling queue thread to quit
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] joining queue thread
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] feeder thread got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485637120
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485637120
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485604352
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485604352
[DEBUG/Consumer-1] ... queue thread joined
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485571584
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485571584
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
[INFO/Consumer-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485538816
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485538816
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485506048
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485506048
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485473280
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485473280
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485440512
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485440512
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485407744
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485407744
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485374976
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485374976
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485342208
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485342208
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485309440
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140730485309440
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
Creating 1 consumers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] telling queue thread to quit
[DEBUG/MainProcess] telling queue thread to quit
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._start_thread()
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._start_thread()
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] Queue._after_fork()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] doing self._thread.start()
[INFO/Consumer-2] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] doing self._thread.start()
[INFO/Consumer-2] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/MainProcess] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... done self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... done self._thread.start()
Consumer-2: 0 * 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] feeder thread got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/MainProcess] feeder thread got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining queue thread
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining queue thread
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... queue thread already dead
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... queue thread already dead
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] Queue._start_thread()
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] Queue._start_thread()
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] doing self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] doing self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] ... done self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] ... done self._thread.start()
Consumer-2: 1 * 1
Consumer-2: 2 * 2
Consumer-2: Exiting
Result: 0 * 0 = 0
Result: 1 * 1 = 1
Result: 2 * 2 = 4
[INFO/Consumer-2] process shutting down
[INFO/Consumer-2] process shutting down
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] telling queue thread to quit
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] telling queue thread to quit
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] telling queue thread to quit
[DEBUG/MainProcess] telling queue thread to quit
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process Consumer-2
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process Consumer-2
[DEBUG/MainProcess] feeder thread got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/MainProcess] feeder thread got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] feeder thread got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] feeder thread got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] joining queue thread
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] joining queue thread
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] ... queue thread joined
[DEBUG/Consumer-2] ... queue thread joined
[INFO/Consumer-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/Consumer-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining queue thread
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining queue thread
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... queue thread joined
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... queue thread joined
```

Do I have to initialize the multiprocessing environment somehow or is it just not possible to do this in a loop of the main process? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Python 2.7.5

Comment: I don't see any increase in memory with multiple calls to `calc`.

Comment: usually you do `tasks.put(None)` if there is `for task in iter(tasks.get, None):` somewhere; otherwise `tasks.join()` would be (fragile but) enough.

Comment: also, I'd expect that each call to the `calc()` function would produce the corresponding output.

Comment: @Bakuriu unfortunately in this minimal example the memory problem is not really showing. What really puzzles me is that if I have this setup I would assume that after the first calc() call has gone through all the objects would be destroyed and created anew in the next call of calc(). But in my real program the memory consumption doubles in the second run. If I start the program again with the parameters of the second run it works fine and that is really strange. I'll try to produce a minimal working example that really shows it but it is rather complex and in multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to the end of **calc()**:

```
for w in consumers:
    w.join()
```

Calling **join()** on your joinable queue blocks until everything on the queue has been consumed, but it doesn't guarantee that the subprocesses have been garbage collected. I suspect you have some objects in your subprocesses lingering in memory since they haven't been joined.